# Zod: at least one field should be valid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, zod

I'm creating a form where users can enter either their email or their phone, they can enter both, but they can't proceed without entering both.
I'm using Zod and react-hook-form

**This is my schema:**

```js
const emailValidator = z.string().email()

export const contactFirstStepSchema = z
    .object({
        email: z
            .string()
            .refine(v => (v ? emailValidator.safeParse(v).success : true), "Invalid email"),
        phone: z.string().refine(value => {
            if (value) return isValidPhoneNumber(value, 'FR')

            return true
        }, "Invalid number"),
        description: z.string().optional()
    })
    .partial()
    .refine(({ email, phone }) => (email === undefined || email === '') && (phone === undefined || phone === ''), {
        message:
            "At least one field should be provided (or both)."
    })
```

However, when I submit the form without entering the both fields, it doesn't work, what should be done in this case?

thank you.

Comment: are email and phone guaranteed they are never `null` ?

Comment: @Arashjahanbakhshan yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `refine` function completely opposite. The return value of the refine callback must be false to throw an error. but in your code, you return true if both were undefined or an empty string.

this is the code you can use:

```
const emailValidator = z.string().email()

export const contactFirstStepSchema = z
    .object({
        email: z
            .string()
            .refine(v => (v ? emailValidator.safeParse(v).success : true), "Invalid email"),
        phone: z.string().refine(value => {
            if (value) return isValidPhoneNumber(value, 'FR')

            return true
        }, "Invalid number"),
        description: z.string().optional()
    })
    .partial()
    .refine(({ email, phone }) => email || phone), { // edited line
        message:
            "At least one field should be provided (or both)."
    })
```

in this edit, the return value will be false, only if both of them have falsy value (`null`, `undefined`, `empty string`, `<=0`). or true if at least one of them have a truly value

Comment: I forgot to answer, thank you its working